# Zabbix Userparameter under Windows working locally, but not from Zabbix Server

Tags: powershell, cmd, zabbix

I have this Userparameter added to my config on a Windows Host:

```
UserParameter=backups.db-zip, powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {Get-ChildItem C: | ForEach-Object{((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).ToString('dd')}}
```

When I run it locally from either powershell or cmd it works. When I run it via Zabbix Agent it throws an error like "The command ForEach-Object... can not be found."

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the VERTICAL LINE? `...m C: ^| For...`

Comment: There was no `ForEach-Object` in the two answers I offered, in my answer to your previous question, _for which I've had absolutely no feedback_. I would suggest however, in this instance, that your -Command is enclosed within doublequotes.

Comment: I also mentioned in my answer to your previous question, that you don't need to touch the execution policy for _`-command`s_ It's only really necessary when running powershell scripts, _`-file`s_.

Comment: Hey Compo, thank you. I think the ForEach-Object is not the problem in my case. Both versions throw errors in Zabbix but work locally (with or without the ForEach-Object). It must be something Zabbix Agent related I assume.

Comment: @ lit
I've tried to escape it. It Does not work either. "Unexpected Token ^ ...". The weired thing is I have other powershell parameters and they work fine. No obvious difference except the fact that there is a for-loop in this one.

Comment: it is driving me nuts^^